# Visual/Spatial Mind Map/Flow Chart File Structure Organization Software?

Tags: software-rec, file-management, organizer-software, mind-mapping, file-organization

**Short story:**
I'm looking for a software to visually organize files. The layout should look something like a mind mapping software, only with files instead of mere text snippets. It should also be capable of previewing the contents of the file.

**Long story:**
The files I want to organize are mostly text or image files. On a more zoomed out, file structure level it should only display perhaps the name of the file, but I'd like to be able to expand/zoom in and view the actual text in the text file and highlight/annotate relevant sections.

I work at an engineering firm where each project generally start as a text document detailing the scope of work. As work progresses this document spawns a large number of branches. Different types of drawings, models and other "input" types of files. These input files are then used in a large number of analyses, creating further branches with various types of results, or "output". Finally the findings are summarized in a series of reports.

It's a rather complex flow, and quickly getting an overview or determining cause and effect can be very time consuming. Viewing a simple file tree in e.g. windows explorer might work for looking into a small analysis. But there's no real trace of which input file spawned which output file. For a non expert it can even be hard to determine what is input and what is output. If you're lucky the engineer might have left you a readme.txt file with some brief explanations, or commented some of the code. The analysis conclusions might be detailed in a report, but there's no trace of which lines in the several thousand line output that spawned a particular conclusion. Arrows/lines connecting the files, or specific lines in the files, with input for the next analysis or conclusions in a report would greatly simplify things.

**Is there any application out there capable of handling at least parts of what I'm asking for?**

UPDATE: I've now tried The Brain, but it didn't do it for me. Perhaps what I'm looking for is some type of file manager/browser. I want to organize a file structure without actually moving the files (e.g symlinks). I'd like to view this new file structure in a kind of workflow/mind mapping software layout. I'd like the capability to view/preview text files and images "live", just by zooming/expanding the selected file. I'd like to add comments and annotate each step and file. Preferably also the content of each file.

Comment: There are many charting/graphing/structuring applications but I've not seen one with functionality to hotlink text files.

Answer (score 2):

Would a mindmap with metadata and links to the files work? It would avoid using a layer of symlinks. [Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) (GPL) can do this for sure. I've seen people use it to manage project resources and documentation. They have a list of similar programs on their wiki that may also suit you.

Answer (score 1):

I've used one called [The Brain](http://www.thebrain.com/).  It's not free, but the trial does include the full featured version, after which you can choose which feature set you want to pay for.

It does allow for linking/associating files with the different 'nodes'.

I used it to try and map out a corporate network structure , attaching backup configs and manuals and such.  Pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

You can put links to files in [MindManager](http://www.mindjet.com/products/mindmanager). I love it but it is expensive. I am not sure if you can zoom in to edit the file text as you want, but you can create a map containing your files' names with links to them.